# Cross compile on windows linux subsystem and deploy to target using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, cross-platform

I have a beaglebone black for which I want to cross compile on the windows linux subsystem but deploy it afterwards onto the target (Beaglebone). I have installed the cross compiler on the linux subsystem but I'm not quite sure how to hook everything up on the visual studio end.

Basically I want to:

- Write code in Visual Studio 2017
- Build on the Windows Linux Subsystem
- Deploy on the ARM Target over SSH (Beaglebone black)

Comment: See this MSDN blog: [Targeting the Windows Subsystem for Linux from Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/02/08/targeting-windows-subsystem-for-linux-from-visual-studio/).

Comment: I have read that blog but I can't configure VS17 to use the linaro toolchain and build for ARM instead of x64/x86

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two steps are straightforward and there are several guides for you to read, one of which has been referenced above.

Using WSL, you're only going to be able to target x86 with a simple project type (MSBuild). But you can at least get it compiled and maybe do some debugging.

For the Beaglebone you'll need a makefile project. Visual Studio sees the makefile as a black box that generates a build target. Inside that box you will write the commands to cross-compile to an ARM executable and copy it to the appropriate destination. Build errors will be reported back to Visual Studio but you won't be able to debug the cross-compiled application on the Beaglebone.

You'll find some information [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/visual-c-for-linux-development/) to get you started with makefile projects.